# Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, attributeerror, datareader

as I am trying to print financial data:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
style.use('ggplot')
start=dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end=dt.datetime(2016,12,31)
df= web.DataReader('ERIE', 'google', start, end)
print(df.head())
```

I get the error that df does not exist, or more specifically:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
print(df.head(5))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 51, in __str__
return self.__unicode__()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 582, in __unicode__
width, _ = console.get_console_size()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\console.py", line 77, in get_console_size
terminal_width, terminal_height = get_terminal_size()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\terminal.py", line 33, in get_terminal_size
return shutil.get_terminal_size()
File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 1071, in get_terminal_size
size = os.get_terminal_size(sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I have no clue how to fix this, as this code seems to be working with everyone else who is trying it. I am just a beginner, so any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you!
Greetings, Tristan

Comment: Looks like `sys.__stdout__` is `None` in this case.  Not sure why...

What if you add `import sys` to your header?  Same issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug in `shutil` library:

https://bugs.python.org/issue24920

https://bugs.python.org/issue24966

It seems, you should change the way you started you code (from GUI or from shell and similar)

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Comment: @RomanMindlin Would you explain more on your answer? I don't understand what you mean by "you should change the way you started you code (from GUI or from shell and similar)".

Comment: @BsHe You should try to change environment for you code, execute it from shell, not from IDLE. Also, try to update python version, this issue was fixed in 3.5

Comment: @RomanMindlin I also noticed executing from shell solved the problem. I am using version 3.5. The problem can be solved by defining sys.__stdout__ variable [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126368/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-fileno)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution, but at least a workaround.

You can use shutil's [get_terminal_size()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size) instead. There's also a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size) available for python 2.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {
"country" :["Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"],
"capital" :["Brasilia", "Moscow", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Pretoria"],
"area" : [8.516, 17.10, 3.286, 9.597, 1.221],
"population" : [200.4, 143.5, 1252, 1357, 52.98] }

brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)

brics
```

An easy hack would be to shift your work to the Python shell, instead of IDLE (in my case, working on IDLE was the problem, but this same code ran perfectly on the Python Shell)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've used a screen session in the terminal to start up spyder IDE for python. I've accidentally terminated the screen session, but spyder kept working with this error. After I restarted spyder in a new screen session, the error disappeared.