# npyscreen doesn't seem to have installed properly using PIP. How do I get it installed properly?

Tags: python, npyscreen

I'm trying to install npyscreen to my Python 3.6.3 installation. I used PIP and it seemed to work. However when I run a program with import npyscreen I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import npyscreen
  File "E:\Python\npyscreen.py", line 5, in <module>
    class TestApp(npyscreen.NPSApp):
AttributeError: module 'npyscreen' has no attribute 'NPSApp'
```

I'm really inexperienced and totally don't understand how PIP works, where it puts things and how I go about setting up paths etc. Can anyone help this beginner get going?

Comment: Look for the npyscreen source and build from there. If that seems tedious, then try downloading the npyscreen wheel manually and then pip install it.

Comment: Try getting the source from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/npyscreen/

Comment: Thanks. I donwloaded the source and installed it using `python setup.py install` but I still get an error when I try to run the npyscreen demo code:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\glenn\Downloads\npyscreen-4.10.5\EXAMPLE-BOX.py", line 40, in <module>
    App.run()
  File "C:\Users\glenn\Downloads\npyscreen-
... Edited because too long ...
  File "C:\Users\glenn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'`

Comment: Sweet! If your problem is solved then add an answer and mark it correct for future reference.

Comment: Sorry, see above comment Sayan Sil...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126368/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-fileno Here is a similar question.

Comment: I think I got to the bottom of my issues. After ensuring that Curses was installed properly (I got it from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) I discovered that the npyscreen python code would never run from inside IDLE. Running the python code from a command prompt solves it.

Comment: That website is a blessing. Bookmark it.