# Python curses shows an error and I can't handle it

Tags: python, curses

I loaded the curses-module with `pip install windows-curses` and in my IDLE, I typed

```
 import curses

 stdscr = curses.initscr()
```

It produces:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/User/Dropbox/Entwicklung/Python/odd.py", line 3, in <module>
 stdscr = curses.initscr()
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in 
 initscr
 fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

What is wrong? Does it have something to do with my OS' python and the python I installed? I don't understand the difference.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061595/5666087

Comment: Uhm no, but let me check it in more details. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use curses from IDLE. You can code using IDLE but you'd need to run your script from a Command Prompt.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel makes sense and works, thanks. Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're supposed to use curses from IDLE.

You can code using IDLE but you'd need to run your script from a Command Prompt.